# WallclockTimestampExtractor timestamp generated is before processing timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Topology which reads events from `topicA` does some processing during which it sets one of the fields to current timestamp with use of `System.currentTimeMillis` and sends the outcome to `topicB`. This application has `WallclockTimestampExtractor` set as default.

I've set another topology which reads from both topics in order to measure latency per eventType, however, the timestamp which I get from `processorContext.timestamp` **is before the processing timestamp which I set on the payload**. As far as I understand WallclockTimestampExtractor will set the timestamp for the event which will be equal to the time of putting the event in the topic so it should be impossible to have this time to fall before processing time.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime` on topic solved it for me